# Python based endpoint agent OSS project

Tags: python, security

Is there a Open Source project that provides functionality to create/enhance an endpoint / PC-based agent that runs in the background and can perform various activities such as keylogging, contextual mouse click handling, etc?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this discussion (crossbar.io + autobahn)

http://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/2tk6tz/im_looking_for_a_generic_endpointagent_written_in/

Comment: Thanks. Found https://pypi.python.org/pypi/SPADE as well. Maybe need to create a framework myself and Open Source it! Would post the results soon!

Comment: The challenge is the scope i.e. keylogger, contextual mouse clickers, network monitor, file handling capabilities, etc etc would be a BIG project! Quite surprising there is no project available on this front, especially since Python is so widely used and comes default installed on so many platforms. And also the popularity, I almost assumed there would be a project on that!